# Linkedin OAuth2 not working in mobile MeteorJs

Tags: javascript, meteor, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement, linkedin oAuth2 with Meteor. Its working perfect in webpage but it does not work when I run in mobile device or mobile emulator.

```
<template name="createAccount">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 align="center">Create Account</h2>
        <div class="">
            <button class="connectWithLinkedin">Connect with LinkedIn</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


Template.createAccount.created = function(){
    var instance = this;
    console.log('created');
    instance.loginServicesStatus = new ReactiveVar(false);
    instance.checkLoginServices = new ReactiveVar(true);
    instance.autorun(function(){
        if(instance.checkLoginServices.get()){
            if(Accounts.loginServicesConfigured()){
                instance.checkLoginServices.set(false);
                instance.loginServicesStatus.set(true);
            }
        }
    })
}

Template.createAccount.events({
    'click .connectWithLinkedin':function(event,template){
        if(template.loginServicesStatus.get()){
            Meteor.loginWithLinkedin({
                loginStyle:'popup'
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("error encountered "+err);
                }
                else{
                    Router.go('linkedinForm');
                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

The document (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/OAuth-for-mobile-Meteor-clients) says that OAuth2 does not work in mobile in development environment.

So I deployed the app in meteor site and then I am running it with command 'meteor run android --mobile-server http://myproject.meteor.com'

But once the user gives authentication details in the pop up and presses submit, I get the error

```
(android:http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1059) processMessage failed: Error: Error: No hash fragment in OAuth popup?
(android:http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1060) processMessage failed: Stack: Error: No hash fragment in OAuth popup?

at l (http://meteor.local/88f35875f0517637213e3650eb9e5d3b03e2e558.js:141:2263)
at Channel.fire (http://meteor.local/cordova.js:806:23)
at Object.InAppBrowser._eventHandler (http://meteor.local/plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js:39:39)
at cb (http://meteor.local/plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/inappbrowser.js:96:12)
at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (http://meteor.local/cordova.js:293:54)
at processMessage (http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1054:21)
at Function.androidExec.processMessages (http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1091:13)
at pollOnce (http://meteor.local/cordova.js:956:17)

(android:http://meteor.local/cordova.js:1061) processMessage failed: Message: S11 InAppBrowser844315663 {"type":"loadstop","url":"http:\/\/myproject.meteor.com\/_oauth\/linkedin?close&code=AQTttripLI6SIg9booubenZ6FEXRz19vJgXSSAp2030Htqs22-B9oDI_QjoWpRpa9RkGr7b9e5NjuPu2W1U-bkZc-r4ZKB4ZjlbZvAnDhZTN6S1JSc8&state=rkCJfdL3oXxzvZMPy"}
```